# PsiElement.firstChild vs PsiElement.children.first()

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, compiler-construction, intellij-plugin

I expected `PsiElement.firstChild` and `PsiElement.children.first()` to always return the same `PsiElement`, however, it turns out that (considering KtElements):

- for `KtBlockExpression` they are not the same: `firstChild` returns a left curly brace and `children.first()` returns the first expression of the body.
- for `KtTypeReference` they are the same thing.

So the questions is:

- Why are they not equivalent in general?
- When are the equivalent and when are they different (I am interested mainly in classes derived from `KtElement`)?

Comment: I'd recommend you raise this issue at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development so that IDEA Core team could take a look at it.